# What is the motivation behind defining $[\alpha] + [\beta] = [(\alpha \land \lnot \beta) \lor (\lnot \alpha \land \beta)]$?

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

> Consider $\mathcal{F}$ to be the set of all well-formed formulae (wffs), and $\mathcal{F}/\equiv$ denotes the set of equivalence classes under the equivalence relation induced by $\equiv$ (logical equivalence). Then, $(\mathcal{F}/\equiv, +, \land, 0, 1)$ is a **boolean algebra** (defined as a ring), where the operation $+$ is defined as $[\alpha] + [\beta] = [(\alpha \land \lnot \beta) \lor (\lnot \alpha \land \beta)]$. $[\alpha]$ refers to the equivalence class of wff $\alpha$. Clearly, $0$ refers to all contradictions and $1$ refers to all tautologies.

What is the **motivation** behind defining $[\alpha] + [\beta] = [(\alpha \land \lnot \beta) \lor (\lnot \alpha \land \beta)]$? This surely works, i.e. under this definition of $+$, $(\mathcal{F}/\equiv, +, \land, 0, 1)$ is indeed a boolean algebra, but this definition looks very **unintuitive**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It corresponds to symmetric difference,

$$A\triangle B=(A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)=(A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c)\,,$$

in the algebra of sets and gives you not just a Boolean algebra, but a [Boolean ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring), just as $\langle\wp(X),\triangle,\cap,\varnothing,X\rangle$ is a Boolean ring of sets.

Comment: The symmetric difference in the case of sets is certainly intuitive, but could you throw some light on **what it really means** in the context of wffs?

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine: A point is in the symmetric difference of $A$ and $B$ iff it belongs to exactly one of $A$ and $B$; $(\alpha\land\neg\beta)\lor(\neg\alpha\land\beta)$ is true iff exactly one of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is true.